# Safe way for manually concatenating JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I need to manually concatenate several blocks of JavaScript code. Is there something I should consider doing?

E.g., is it a good idea to wrap each block inside an immediately executed function and prefix this function with a `;`?

What else should I watch out for to avoid problems with the concatenated version?

Comment: Why not use a minifier like UglifyJS? `cat file1.js file2.js | uglifyjs -o out.js`

Comment: Of course I could use a minifier to get this working, but I'm curious. So it's just out of interest, to learn :-).

Comment: If you're in control of those pieces of code then that should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that a syntax error in one of the blocks will prevent the entire code from running.

Wrapping each block inside a function might break badly written code that expects to be run in the global scope.

To deal with syntax errors, your best bet is to use a code compiler, such as YUI Compressor or Google Closure Compiler, to process each block of code, be notified of any syntax errors up front and reduce their length in bytes while you're at it.

The code output by any such tool is highly standardized and probably has all the semicolons in the right place. You can then just concatenate the compressed versions.

Then you will need to deal with runtime errors (exceptions), generated by one block of code and stopping execution of all subsequent blocks. To deal with that, just wrap each block of code in a `try {...} catch (err) {}` so that execution continues over to the next block in case of an error.

You can do this either before or after the code compilation phase.

Comment: But even those tools do have to follow some best practices, don't they? As I pointed out I'm not interested in how I could avoid doing it manually, but in getting to know what to watch out for. Of course these tools solve the problem, so that I do not have to do it any more, but basically it only moves the question to another level.

Comment: The problem is very complicated. What if one of your blocks missed a close bracket `}` somewhere, and a following block has a `}` too much? It would change the code of all those blocks in unexpected ways, assuming it doesn't cause a syntax error. That's why I suggest using a tool to check the syntax of each single block and re-format its code in a standard way. Doing it by hand is very error-prone.